# Can getSelection() be applied to just a certain element (not the whole document)?

Tags: javascript, string, getselection

I was testing out the `getSelection()` method, and I wanted my program to get the selected text in a certain paragraph of text and display it in a div tag. I used the following code:

```
var txt = document.getSelection();
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "The text you have selected is: " + txt + ".";
```

However, I want the program to only get selections made in the paragraph itself, not in the entire document. I tried using `document.getElementById("id").getSelection();` but it didn't work.

How can I make it so `getSelection()` only applies to a certain element?

Comment: Sorry everyone...I'm just a beginner...I'm pretty sure this is a really simple question.

Comment: use jquery framework!!! makes life so much easier

Comment: Sorry! I haven't actually learned jQuery yet. As you can see, I'm really a beginner.

Comment: @user1551482 jQuery won't help one little bit for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach, tested only in Chromium 19 (Which supports `textContent`, for Internet Explorer `innerText` would have to be used instead):

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}

var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    o = document.getElementById('output');

b.onmouseup = function(e){
    var selText = getSelectedText(),
        targetElem = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (selText && targetElem == 'p') {
        o.textContent = 'You selected the text: "' + selText + '" from a ' + targetElem + ' element.';
    }
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3QtgG/1/).

Comment: I just wanted to check...what is the "e" parameter for in the b.onmouseup line? (As in what does the variable stand for?)

Comment: That's the `event` parameter, which holds information on what was acted on, what nodes, and such. It's worth adding a `console.log(e)` to the function, and then inspecting it to see what's there. Particularly in Chrome, and other Webkit browsers, where you can expand the details.

Answer (score 3):

`getSelection()` is only available as a method of `window` and `document`. If you want to get a Range representing just the portion of the user selection that lies within a particular node, here's a function to do that, using my Rangy library (the code to do without the library would be longer and is beyond my enthusiasm to write right now):

```
function getSelectedRangeWithin(el) {
    var selectedRange = null;
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    var elRange = rangy.createRange();
    elRange.selectNodeContents(el);
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        selectedRange = sel.getRangeAt(0).intersection(elRange);
    }
    elRange.detach();
    return selectedRange;
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but while displaying it shows multiple selections, how to show a single selection?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
        else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
                    else {
                            var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
                            if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

written in coffeescript:

```
getSelected = ->
  if window.getSelection
    return window.getSelection()
  else if document.getSelection
    return document.getSelection()
  else
    selection = document.selection and document.selection.createRange()
    return selection.text  if selection.text
    return false
  false
```

delicious javascript